# Unable to fetch data using Spring JPA Native Query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I have a spring JPA Application. I am using Spring Boot with Spring JPA native query to fetch the data but I am not getting any results. Database used is Oracle 11g. Can anyone please help me to fix it ?

Here is the code.

**Repository**

public interface RoseRepository extends JpaRepository {

```
@Query(value = "SELECT  RWM.RIG_WELL_ID as id,RM.RIG_NAME as name FROM RIG_WELL_MASTER RWM JOIN RIG_UNIT_MAPPER RUM ON RWM.fk_rig_master_id = RUM.fk_rig_master_id JOIN RIG_UNIT RU ON ru.rig_unit_code = RUM.UNIT_CODE JOIN RIG_MASTER RM ON RM.RIG_MASTER_ID =  RWM.FK_RIG_MASTER_ID AND RWM.START_TIME=TO_DATE(?1,'DD-MON-YY') AND RU.UNIT_NAME=?2", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<RigDetails> fetchRigsForAUnit(String startTime,String unitName);

}
```

**interface**

```
public interface RigDetails {

    String getId();
    String getName();

}
```

**Service**

```
@Service

    public class RoseService  {

    @Autowired
        private RoseRepository roseRepository; 

        public List<RigDetails> fetchRigsForAUnit(String startTime, String unitName) {
            List<RigDetails> rigList = null;
            try{    
                rigList = roseRepository.fetchRigsForAUnit(startTime, unitName);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            return rigList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: I am not getting any error. It just displays the query in the console. But the result is empty. I am using this dialect in application.properties  - spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect. Any idea what could be the issues ?

Comment: If you execute the query manually i.e. in a console, what happens?

Comment: It gives the result when i execute it manually. It the issue related to the Spring boot jar version. I am using 2.1.0

Comment: Another observation is, When i execute a native query through application using only two tables, it gives me result but when i introduce the 3rd table to join then there is no result.

Comment: > but when i introduce the 3rd table to join then there is no result
then your join condition / parameters are wrong. Show us the values you are passing as an argument to the method, the statement you execute manually that works and the data in the tables that you expect as a result.